# AJAX call to Django View returns None to data

Tags: python, django, ajax

I have been trying to get data that I send using AJAX with a Django view.
I have this AJAX call

```js
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "{% url 'change_publish_status' %}",
    value: {"company_id": company_id, "published": published},
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: {"X-CSRFToken": '{{ csrf_token }}'}
});
```

and I'd like to access the company_id and the published variables from the django view.
I have tried many things

- `self.request.POST.get('company_id')` --> returns None
- `self.request.POST.get('company_id', None)` --> returns None
- `self.request.body` --> returns b''

This is my view right now

```py
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class ChangePublishStatus(TemplateView):
    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        company_id = self.request.POST.get('company_id', None)
        published_status = self.request.POST.get('published') == "true"

        print(company_id)

        return JsonResponse({"status": "ok"})

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return redirect("list")
```

Answer (score 0):

To send the data in the `POST` call, pass the data in the `data` argument rather than `value`.

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "{% url 'change_publish_status' %}",
    data: {"company_id": company_id, "published": published},
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: {"X-CSRFToken": '{{ csrf_token }}'}
});
```